# Limit of a sequence?

Tags: limits

The question and my attempt are here:

$$a_n=\frac{2^n+n!+n}{5^n+3n^2-1}$$

---

I've tried to do it by a strategy suggested by my textbook (see below):

> **Strategy** $\mathbf{3.1}$ To evaluate the limit of a complicated quotient.
>
> 1. Identify the dominant term.
> 2. Divide both numerator and denominator by the dominant term.
> 3. Apply the Combination Rules.
>
> Note that $n!$ dominates $c^n$, and, for $|c|>1$ and $p>0$, $c^n$ dominates $n^p$'

---

$$\begin{align*}
a_n&=\frac{\frac{2^n}{n!}+\frac{n!}{n!}+\frac{n}{n!}}{\frac{5^n}{n!}+\frac{3n^2}{n!}-\frac1{n!}}\\\\
&=\frac{\frac{2^n}{n!}+1+\frac{n}{n!}}{\frac{5^n}{n!}+\frac{3n^2}{n!}-\frac1{n!}}\;.
\end{align*}$$

$\left\{\frac{1^n}{n!}\right\}$, $\left\{\frac{n}{n!}\right\}$, and $\left\{\frac1{n!}\right\}$ are basic null sequences.

Hence, by combination rules

$$\text{limit as }n\text{ tends to infinity }=\frac{0+1+0}{0+0-0}=\frac10=\text{ Undefined}$$

But my limit is undefined and wolfram alpha says it is infinity, so any help in understanding where I went wrong would be appreciated.  Thanks.

Comment: $\frac{1}{0} = \infty$

Comment: @Trevor Observe that your sequence is positive for all $\;n\in\Bbb N\;$, and thus the limit is infinity.

Comment: @BolzWeir ...or $\;-\infty\;$ if zero is approached from the left...or none, if zero is approached from both sides.

Comment: Great, thanks for the clarification.

Comment: That factorial is gonna run away with the goods.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another way to see your limit really is $\;+\infty\;$ :

$$\frac{2^n+n!+n}{5^n+3n^2-1}\ge\frac{n!}{4\cdot5^n}\xrightarrow[n\to\infty]{}\infty$$

Answer (score 0):

Honestly, how aould you expect a *defined* quotient $\frac ab$ when the limit might be $\infty$? Whenever $\frac ab$ for real $a,b$ is defined, the quotient is certainly a (finite) real number.

So what we need to keep in mind is that, as $n\to\infty$, the numerator *tends* to $1$ and the denominator *tends* to zero. How the limit $1$ in the denominator is reached does not play a role. However, for the limit $0$ in the denominator we need to look out for the sign. If the denominator is very small but positive, then its reciprocal wil be large and positive. Hence if the denominator is always (or at least for all big enough $n$) positive, then our "limit" can only be $+\infty$ (by the usual abuse ob language - strictly speaking, the sequence is divergent). If it is (almost) always negative, the limit is $-\infty$; and if it carries both signs infinitely often, we have a problem, or can only sa that $|a_n|\to\infty$.

In the specific example, the denominator is always positive, hence $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{2^n+n!+n}{5^n+3n^2-1}=+\infty$$